# JavaScript function as argument of function on a variable?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I have:

```
function verificarNumero(test, num) {
    return (test(num));
};

var resultadoTesteMultiplos = verificarNumero(function (num){return (num % 10 == 0);}, num1);
```

This function is supposed to find out if a number is a multiple of 10.
I know there are simpler ways to do it, but I really want to make this work.

I want to be able to do something like `console.log(resultadoTesteMultiplos(10));` but the console returns "resultadoTesteMultiplos is not a function", and "num1 is undefined."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok. Where do you define `num1`?

Comment: I'm passing it as an argument, so I don't need to define it... right?

Comment: What you need is a function returning a function.

Comment: @IgorSílva — Only if you are happy with the value being `undefined` when the function you are passing it to receives it (and you haven't declared it either, so you'll get a ReferenceError for that).

Comment: Why do you want to wrap a function you created im a function?

Comment: I know, but i have another script exactly like this one but instead of having a function as argument it has a function "test", and i pass that as an argument and it works.

Comment: @Bálint I don't know, my teacher challenged me to make it work then told me to forget about it, but know this won't come out of my head.

Comment: well in the end -> don't care about another function -> ask yourself what u want to achieve or try to understand what happens inside the other function and ask about it here ;)

Comment: @MarcelD I just got it to work from another answer, I needed to make the function verificarNumero return a function too. Thanks :)

Comment: @Igor `function x(func, num) { var s = "(function() {_})()"; for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) { s = s.replace("_", "return (function() {_})();" } s = s.replace("_", "return func(num);"); return eval(s);}` That should get your teacher covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you meant to curry but only got half way:

```
function verificarNumero(test) {
  return function(num) {
    return test(num);
  };
}

var resultadoTesteMultiplos = verificarNumero(function(num) {
  return (num % 10 == 0);
});

console.log(resultadoTesteMultiplos(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define `num1` variable your code should work and the type of the `resultadoTesteMultiplos` is `boolean`. See the working snippet below please:

```js
var num1 = 10;
function verificarNumero(test, num) {
  return (test(num));
};

var resultadoTesteMultiplos = verificarNumero(function(num) {
  return (num % 10 == 0);
}, num1);
console.log(typeof resultadoTesteMultiplos);
console.log(resultadoTesteMultiplos);
```

Comment: Yes i tried that, what i wanted was to pass a value to num1 without having to set it like that.

Comment: @IgorSílva, ok, I understand. The above answer should work too, but I see the difference between mine an the accepted answer and I'm happy you found what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Return a function from `verificarNumero`, not the result of the function.

```
function verificarNumero (cb) {
    return function (num) {
        return cb.apply(this, [num]);
    }    
};

resultadoTesteMultiplos = verificarNumero(function (num) {
    return (num % 10 == 0);
};

console.log(resultadoTesteMultiplos(10));
```